# Git - Unable to merge after updating index to assume local files as unchanged

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-merge

I marked a local file as unchanged by updating the index, using:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file1>
```

Though, `file1` is present in the remote repository. Now when I'm trying to merge a remote branch by:

```
git checkout myBranch
git merge origin/myRemoteBranch
```

I get an error which says:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
       file1
Please commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I can not commit or stash anything because `git status` says "nothing to commit", after marking `file1` as `assume-unchanged`. How can I merge the remote branch into the local one and keeping the local changes on `file1` untracked.

Answer (score 0):

When you are merging other branch into your local branch, changes won't happen to other branch (remote or not).

I assume, that you have a file, that exists on remote branch already and don't want git to track additional changes to that file. If this is the case, you should create `.gitignore` file and add `file1` in there. 
Read: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: That sounds like one solution, but when I update `.gitignore` on my branch and later that gets merged into `master` eventually, I don't want `file1` on master to get ignored. Edited my question for better clarity.